# adf table filter with selectOne doesn't fires filter event on value change

Tags: oracle-adf

I am new to ADF

My Table has selectOne as filter but when a select a value it doesn't fires filter event. I have to press Enter to do so.

Please help me to fire event on selectOne valueChange.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `autoSubmit` property set to `true`, otherwise you have to do submit action after changing the value.